# Bottle response does not trigger ajax callback

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback, bottle

I have the following ajax post using jquery:

```
$.post("/login", {}, function(data){
    alert("yolo");
});
```

Which is triggered by a button click and where '/login' maps to my server (using Bottle):

```
@route('/login', method='POST')
def login():
    return "something"
```

The problem I'm facing is that my callback is never called and I instead get back an html page with "something" in my body.

How can I let my browser treat my server response as data rather than as a new html page?

Comment: It shouldn't be doing so anyway, you should not be getting a redirect. How is `$.post` getting triggered? Can we see the surrounding JS and HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are triggering your `$.post` with something like a `.click` on a submit button inside a `<form>` tag. If this is the case, then your form is going to do a standard submit and be redirected by your server to the action in question. To prevent this (and allow the ajax to occur instead) you need to prevent the browsers default form submit behavior. This can easily be done like so:

```
 $('#IDofYourForm').submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
```

Comment: Yes, I did have a post in the form tag, and I believe some of my testing may have been invalid due to browser caching. Thanks Fresheyeball!